# FQL not returning photos tagged with friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I am trying to use FQL to get a list of my own photos that have friends tagged in them. The friends are specified by their name or part of their name. i.e input from a text box

So far I have come up with the FQL below, which almost works, but...

Can anyone tell me why the first query returns a list of records but the second query returns nothing? the only difference between the two is the second one searches on just part of the person's name i.e  "laura" vs "lau"

FQL 1

```
SELECT object_id, src_big, src_big_width, src_big_height, aid 
FROM photo 
WHERE object_id in (
    SELECT object_id
    FROM photo_tag 
    WHERE subject in (
        SELECT uid 
        FROM user 
        WHERE (strpos(lower(name),"laura") >=0 ) 
        AND (uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) )) 
)
AND owner = me()
```

FQL 2

```
SELECT object_id, src_big, src_big_width, src_big_height, aid 
FROM photo 
WHERE object_id in (
    SELECT object_id
    FROM photo_tag 
    WHERE subject in (
        SELECT uid 
        FROM user 
        WHERE (strpos(lower(name),"lau") >=0 ) 
        AND (uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) )) 
)
AND owner = me()
```

Comment: I can't explain why this happens, but I've seen it too. Searching with a partial name word on Facebook never seems to return as many results as when you search with a full name word.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Facebook has a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/435960573102992) in its system so strpos doesn't work as expected in sub queries. As a workaround you could try splitting it into two queries - one that finds list of id-s:

```
SELECT uid 
        FROM user 
        WHERE (strpos(lower(name),"lau") >=0 ) 
        AND (uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) )
```

And a second one that uses this list:

```
SELECT object_id, src_big, src_big_width, src_big_height, aid 
FROM photo 
WHERE object_id in (
    SELECT object_id
    FROM photo_tag 
    WHERE subject in (111,222,333,444,555)
)
AND owner = me()
```